# Mysterious Memory Limit Exceeded; Segmentation Fault error on sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

So, segmentation fault, or memory limit exceeded error occurs when, program tries to access memory out of program stack or you have no more memory left to be allocated to the program.

Edit: When I wrote this question, I was unaware about debugger in programming language. But now that I know, this program runs and all the memory of arrays are allocated in the start of the program.

So my question:

Why this C code is giving segmentation fault error?
This code is the implementation of sieve of Eratosthenes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LIMIT   10000000
#define PRIMES  700000
int is_prime[LIMIT];
int prime[PRIMES];

main()
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++)
        is_prime[i] = 1;
    is_prime[0] = is_prime[1] = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++)
        if (is_prime[i])
            for (j = i*i; j < LIMIT; j += i)
                is_prime[j] = 0;

    j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < LIMIT && j < PRIMES; i++)
        if (is_prime[i])
            prime[j++] = i;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please debug...

Comment: First build your program with debug information, this is done with the `-g` switch to GCC. Then run your program in the `gdb` debugger.

Comment: Hi @admin, please help me get privilege of posting question. i don't know how to correct this question.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Sorry, I was new to programming, I didn't knew of debugger, actually I hardly knew the meaning of 'debug'. Please help me get out of question limit.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks a lot for your efforts in writing the suggestion. I didn't knew of debugger back then. I have only read ANSI C by Dennis Ritchie and Brian Kernighan. There I didn't found information about debugger. Please help me get out of question limit imposed by stack overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        for (j = i*i; j < LIMIT; j += i)
```

The `i*i` in there can overflow, resulting in a large *negative* number. That makes the subsequent `is_prime[j]` access the array way out of bounds. That should be:

```
        for (j = i+i; j < LIMIT; j += i)
```

Comment: Thanks very much.
Declaring i and j as long long will also do.